# Hibernate Database session.save does not add record in database

Tags: hibernate, session

while working on a project using Hibernate ,JSF , I came up with a problem.From what it seems, my program has a problem storing data through the addTemp method used in this Roofhelper.java file

```
public class RoofHelper {

SessionFactory factory = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RoofHelper RoofM = new RoofHelper();

}

public String emailAvailable(String email) {
    String result;
    Transaction tx = null;
    Session session = null;
    session = factory.openSession();
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from User user where user.email= :email").setParameter("email", email);
        User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
        tx.commit();
        if (user == null) {
            result = "a";
        } else {
            result = "na";
        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = "dbp";
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;
}

/* Add to database a  temp user */
public String addTemp(String email, String password, String fname, String lname, int phoneNumber, Boolean buyer, Boolean seller, Boolean renter, Boolean tenant) {
    String result;
    Session session = null;
    session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Temp temp = new Temp(fname, lname, email, password, phoneNumber, buyer, seller, renter, tenant);
        session.persist(temp);
        tx.commit();
        result = "s"; // success
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
            result = "f";//failure
        }
        result = "ff";
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

`}`

while the emailAvailable method executes just fine,the addTemp is just stuck with returning the "ff" string.

Comment: Well. In this case Hibernate is throwing an exception. What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Hey @Desorder , check this txt , I think it has info from the Apache tomcat output https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48247518/stuff.txt

Comment: I am sure it all boils down to this problem : org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : roof.Temp.email

Answer (score 1):

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : roof.Temp.email
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:132)
    ...
```

Your stacktrace is saying that Hibernate is complaining about an email field being null.
Are you setting this field properly?